# Cant display the google maps when release key is used( for publishing the app)

Tags: android

My app.apk file works fine with the debug key in google maps. But when i use the release key its not displaying the map properly(only grid lines seen). I created the release key by following the steps in othr posts. Also used adb to install the app ( thro cmd prompt).

Any Suggestions

Comment: Read here: http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. i followed as told in the last para but map not loaded properly even after that.

Answer (score 1):

For Debug:

> Map key = generated from your keystore file of your system
>
> Apk = you can use signed or unsigned

For Market;

> Map key = generated from the keystore which you used to sign the apk
>   to publish on market
>
> APK = Signed apk

Comment: shd the android market user and user for generating the release key be same?

Comment: release key is not working when i m checking before publish is thr any solution for this? i followed all the mentioned steps but not working is thr anyway i can display the map in release key.